# Why does $\zeta(3)$ appear in the expression for the anomalous magnetic moment?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, magnetic-moment

The anomalous magnetic moment, to fourth order in $\alpha$, contains $\zeta(3)$. Is there a simple explanation for the appearance of this value of the Riemann zeta function?

Comment: Because it pops up when evaluating various definite integrals? Zeta functions also appear when studying blackbody radiation. $\zeta(3)$ is not really any more exotic than, say, $\pi$, $e$, or $\gamma$.

Answer (score 2):

$\zeta(3)$ is a simple convergent infinite series of rationals, $1+1/8+1/27+1/64+\ldots$. It often pops up when evaluating definite integrals, typically because the integrand can be Taylor-expanded and then integrated term-by-term.

I don’t know whether this is the case for the fourth-order magnetic moment integral that gives rise to $\zeta(3)$. But it is definitely the case for a [blackbody integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_gas) (for the number density of a photon gas) that also gives rise to it.

This constant is common enough that it even has a name, [Apéry’s constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant), after the mathematician who proved that it is irrational. Remarkably, no one knows whether it is transcendental!

There is no reason to think of $\zeta(3)$ as any more exotic than, say, $\pi$, $e$, or $\gamma$, other than its unknown transcendentalism.

Comment: In this case, does the 3 of zeta(3) arise because the calculation involves a TRIPLE definite integral? (I am just trying to get a good intuition about Apery's constant).

Comment: @frauke If you are asking about the blackbody case, it’s a single integral, not a triple one.